# Odeint and Curve fit of scipy give warning and gives wrong results

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, odeint

I'm troubled by the warnings of odeint and curve fit. So the thing I want to do is:

my 1st problem is that curve fit and odeint gives warnings as below repeatedly for the 3 data sets(6 warnings in total), but meanwhile curve_fit does give results seemingly correct.

> 828: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated

> 247: ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.

** the 2nd problem is for integrated curves, with the EXACT SAME code just by executing it multiple times, it gives differents results.  It's seems to have a period of repetition, after a few executions, it gives correct curves, but on the next execution, it become once again incorrect and so on. Maybe a problem of instability?**

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pathlib as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def loadData(path):    
    with open(path,"r") as fid:
        res=np.loadtxt(fid,comments="#")
    return res

def modeleeq(a,N,p,we,wp):
    res=(we*a/p[0])**p[1] + (wp*a/p[2])**p[3]
    return res

#get path
chemin=pl.Path(input("Paste the path to the directory containing data files\n"))

#get we and wp in array 3X2
wewp=loadData(chemin/'wewp.dat').transpose()

#plotting
plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
colors = ['#79ccff', '#f78db4', '#a07ffb']

files = pl.Path(chemin).glob("a_dadN*")
para=[]
for i,f in enumerate(files):
    res=loadData(f)
    a=res[:,0]
    dadN=res[:,1]
    we=wewp[i,0]
    wp=wewp[i,1]
    
    #exp data    
    ax1.scatter(a,dadN,c=colors[i],marker="x", label = f"test {i+1}")
    
    #evaluation of parameters
    modele=lambda a, *p: (we*a/p[0])**p[1] + (wp*a/p[2])**p[3]  #p=[ge,me,gp,mp]
    p, pcov= curve_fit(modele,a,dadN, p0 = [2e5,0,1e5,0])
    para.append(p)
    ax1.plot(a,modele(a,*p),c=colors[i],label=f"test {i+1} identification")
    
    #intergration
    a0=a.min() #initial condition
    N = np.linspace(0, 4000)
    aitgr=odeint(modeleeq,a0,N,args=(p,we,wp))
    ax2.plot(N,aitgr,c=colors[i],label = f"test {i+1} integration")
#the following code is just for adding titles and print the identified paras
#so I won't put them here
```

Big thanks to you all!

Comment: any chance to post some data?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4x62bqza2e2fhe/data.zip?dl=0    Here's the link to the 3 data files. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think here are a few issues. First it is clear that the two addends are very similar. So it can, and actually does, happen that the data cannot distinguish between the two. Scaling is a second issue. Having fit parameters spanning orders of magnitude is usually not a good idea. In fact, the gamma just rescale the W. Hence, one can easily rewrite the function as `( f1 * a )**e1` One fits `f1` and calculates `gamma` by knowing `f1=W/gamma`. Another issue is the possibility of negative powers of a negative number coming up. So one should use either `abs( f1 )` or `f1**2`. With this in mind I modified the code and got the result below. From the fit results in the second and third case, one can see that either `f1=0` or the exponents are almost equal. In such a case it is normal that the covariance matrix cannot be determined.

Finally, when it comes to integrating / plotting `a(N)` The differential equation is somewhat of type `da / dN = a**k` so we have `da / a**k = dN` integrating will give `a**(-k+1) = N+N0` so a(N) =  1 / (N + N0 )**( 1 / (k-1) ). As the initial slope is positive `N0 < 0` and the function diverges at `N0`. Numerical integration beyond this value does not make sense.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def loadData(path):    
    with open(path,"r") as fid:
        res=np.loadtxt(fid,comments="#")
    return res


def simplified_model(a, N, f1, e1, f2, e2 ):
    dadN = ( np.fabs( f1 )  * a )**e1  + ( np.fabs( f2 ) * a )**e2
    return dadN

plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot( 1, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot( 1, 2, 2)

colors = ['#79ccff', '#f78db4', '#a07ffb']

para = list()
for i in range( 3 ):
    res=loadData( "a_dadN_{}.dat".format( i + 1 ) )
    a = res[ ::, 0 ]
    dadN = res[ ::, 1 ]
    # ~we = wewp[i, 0 ]
    # ~wp = wewp[ i, 1 ]

    def model_wrapper(a, ge, me, gp, mp ):
        return simplified_model(a, 0, ge, me, gp, mp )

    #exp data    
    ax1.scatter( a, dadN, c=colors[i], marker="x", label = f"test {i+1}" )

    print(i)

    al = np.linspace( min(a), max(a), 50 )
    guess = [ .2 + i, 2.0, 2, 2.2 ]
    dal = np.fromiter( ( model_wrapper( av, *guess ) for av in al ), np.float )
    ax1.plot( al, dal, color=colors[i], ls=':')
    p, pcov= curve_fit(model_wrapper, a, dadN, p0 = guess, maxfev=100000 )
    print( p )
    dalf = np.fromiter( ( model_wrapper( av, *p ) for av in al ), np.float )
    ax1.plot( al, dalf, color=colors[i])

    #intergration
    a0 = a.min() #initial condition
    N = np.linspace(0, 4000, 100000)
    aitgr=odeint( simplified_model, a0, N,args=tuple(p) )
    ax2.plot( N , aitgr, c=colors[i], label = f"test {i+1} integration")
    ax2.set_ylim([1e-4,1e-2])
    ax2.set_yscale("log")

plt.show()
```

providing

[image: results]